# bcdedit /export fails with "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: windows-10, bcdedit

On Windows 10.0.15063 Build 15063 when I run bcdedit /export testing.bcd I get:-

```
E:\>bcdedit /export testing.bcd
The store export operation has failed.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However, I can successfully run bcdedit or bcdedit /enum or bcdedit /v to get a list of entries in the boot record.

```
E:\>bcdedit /v

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=F:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {19e27371-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
resumeobject            {19e27370-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
displayorder            {19e27371-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
                        {19e2736d-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {19e27371-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {19e27372-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {19e27370-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {19e2736d-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10 New
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {19e2736e-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {19e2736c-f9f7-11e6-8927-d5107015d67d}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto
```

I'm running these commands in an elevated dos prompt.  I've tried running the export from several locations with the same result.  Does this indicate that there are issues with the Boot Configuration Data?

I'm attempting to troubleshoot another issue with [0x80004005 Errors stopping Windows Creator updates on Windows 10](https://serverfault.com/questions/893614/windows-10-creator-updates-failing-with-0x80004005-error).  I'm trying to determine if perhaps the updates are failing due to an issue with the boot configuration and whether it would be worth attempting to recreate the boot configuration for the system.